# Is there any way to get the 'Away' Overwatch League skins?

Tags: overwatch

You can buy skins of the teams in the overwatch league, but it seems your only choice is buying the Colored 'Local' skin.

I'd like to buy the 'Visitor' White skin, but can't seem to find a way to do so.

Is it possible?

Comment: In OWL, "home" teams wear their colors, and "away" teams wear white. This has been repeatedly confirmed by the shoutcasters when introducing the teams.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is currently no way to purchase the "Away team" white colour skins - These seem to mostly be for spectating purposes, to easily distinguish teams at a glance. There's no confirmation that these (or similar skins) won't eventually become available however.

Comment: In OWL, "home" teams wear their colors, and "away" teams wear white. This has been repeatedly confirmed by the shoutcasters when introducing the teams.